# '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Robot'

Tags: c++

I have an error in line 58 of the code : Robot robot = robot(seglist[0]...) I have tried different things but nothing works. I need to put the numbers that I have in the txt file into a vector and then assigned the values of robotNum, RobotTeam, robotPosX and robotPosY.
Hope someone can help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

struct Robot {
    std::string robotNum;
    std::string robotTeam;
    std::string robotPosX;
    std::string robotPosY;
    public:
        Robot(string robotNum = "empty", string robotTeam = "empty", string robotPosX = "empty", string robotPosY = "empty") {
            this->robotNum = robotNum;
            this->robotTeam = robotTeam;
            this->robotPosX = robotPosX;
            this->robotPosY = robotPosY;
}

};

using namespace std;

string* sortArray(string* myArray) {
    
    //cout << "pingas";
    //cout << myArray[6];
    return myArray;
}

int main()
{
    
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("start.txt");
    string line;
    std::vector<Robot> myArray;

    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        string line;

        std::string segment;
        std::vector<std::string> seglist;

        while (std::getline(iss, segment, ','))
        {
            seglist.push_back(segment);
        }
        
        
        Robot robot = Robot(seglist[0], seglist[1], seglist[2], seglist[3]);

        myArray.push_back(robot);
        cout << "\n";
    }


    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        string myArray[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            myfile >> myArray[i];
        }
        //string* arraySorted = sortArray(myArray);
        sort(myArray->begin(), myArray->end(), greater<int>());

        //for (auto& elem : myArray)
        //  cout << elem << " - " << endl;

        
    }
    //cout << myArray[];
    myfile.close();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `Robot robot(seglist[0]...` or even drop the whole intermediate object and do `myArray.emplace_back(seglist[0]...`

Comment: You're combining <cstring> and <string>... do you think that's a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

in struct definition there should be

> std:: namespace

for string in Robot constructor:

```
public:
        Robot(std::string robotNum = "empty", std::string robotTeam = "empty", std::string robotPosX = "empty", std::string robotPosY = "empty") {
```

after that code works for me.

Comment: Lol. He has a `using namespace std;` after the definition of Robot. So before that he's using cstring.